# Blank space after full screen (Emacs on MacOSX)

Tags: macos, emacs, elisp

As shown in the picture, there's some blank space after full screen.

GNU Emacs 24.3.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin, NS apple-appkit-1038.36) of 2013-03-13 on bob.porkrind.org

On Mac OSX 10.10.3 Yosemite

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please add a question, and some background on the function you are calling, actual behaviour and expected behaviour. And add the osx tag.

Comment: I can't tell from your screenshots if the space occurs while the frame is fullscreen, or after toggling to fullscreen and then back. Which is it?

Comment: Hi Chris, it only occurs when in fullscreen mode, and it will be gone if exiting fullscreen.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because Emacs windows are character-oriented, and your monitor's resolution is not an exact multiple of characters in size. You can test this by fiddling with your font, font size and / or screen resolution. You will probably find some combinations where the blank space disappears (though the overall effect may be negative).

Note that this is not a problem unique to Emacs. Many other character-oriented applications behave the same way, e.g. some terminals. Try resizing these types of applications; you will probably notice one of two things:

1. Instead of resizing continually the window dimensions will "jump" as it reaches sizes that can hold more or fewer characters.
2. The window will resize continually, but you will see blank space inside the window border like you are seeing with Emacs.

There is no really good general solution to this for fullscreen windows (Emacs frames). Some systems restrict Emacs' frame to the size of its windows, [leaving a gap](https://superuser.com/questions/751075/emacs-maximized-but-leaves-few-pixels-in-awesome-wm). Others may let the frame be whatever size it wants to be, but this results in the kind of thing that you're seeing.

In general, you'll have to find a combination of settings that make you happy. I have accepted that Emacs' frame doesn't cleanly fill my monitor, but that may not be an acceptable solution to you.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. But I do not think this is a resolution related problem, it has a blank line instead of some blank space at the lower right corner. I updated the screenshots to justify.